# How to pass VertxOptions from command line (like worker threads)

Tags: vert.x, vertx3

How to pass VertxOptions from command line (like worker threads)?

I'm talking about something like this:

```
java -jar fat.jar --workerThreads 40
```

or

```
vertx run server.js --workerThreads 40
```

There is no mention of that parameter in manual or API.

Is there any way to do this?

I know that there is an API:

```
var Vertx = require("vertx-js/vertx");
var vertx = Vertx.vertx({
    "workerPoolSize" : 40
});
```

But when I use that API I get warning from Vertx:

```
You're already on a Vert.x context, are you sure you want to create a new Vertx instance?
```

So I thinking I am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it as a system property with a vertx.options prefix.

So for the fat jar it would be:

```
java -jar fat.jar -Dvertx.options.workerThreads 40
```

---

As for what properties you can set, anything that has a setting in VertxOptions has a corresponding property name: the setter name without the "set" portion.

For example, in code:

```
options.setClusterPort(5555)
```

is equivalent to

```
-Dvertx.options.clusterPort
```

on the command line.

Be warned that the "vertx.options" part is case-sensitive.

Comment: I success with `java -jar -Dvertx.options.workerThreads=40 fat.jar`